# Nightly unittest of django application

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to run an nightly unittest of my django application. This should be done:

1. Update repositories (svn and git) to HEAD (at least my code. Django is from the stable branch)
2. run unittest
3. Report errors by email to people who committed since last successful unittest (but only to people in our company)
4. Create a HTML page with reports (last successful run, .....)

Up to now this is done by a small self made python script. But I like to use an established solution.

Environment: Linux only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) with the proper plugins will do a fine job.

- Create your unittest scripts in django app
- Setup Jenkins to fetch your code from GIT/SVN using the [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Sourcecodemanagement) for that.
- Run your tests as an "Execute shell" command:

```
 python manage.py test myapp --settings=settings
```

- you can use coverage for the test run, and then to use "Html publish reports" [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) in Jenkins to get html reports on the code coverage
- There are plenty of [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Buildreports) for statistics of unit tests, reports, email plugin to email the comitters etc.

Comment: I left the "java world" some years ago, and I am happy in python paradise. Maybe it is time install java again. Thank you for your answer. I will give Jenkins a try.